# Rails validate user entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, flash, rails-activerecord

I am working on a project and relatively very new to Rails. What I wanted to do is redirect the user to the username and email entry form. Here is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def create
    @user = User.create!(user_params)
    flash[:notice] = "#{@user.user_id} was successfully created."
    redirect_to movies_path
end
```

Here's my model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :user_id, uniqueness: true
end
```

What I wanted to do is just send the user back to the new user view by using flash if user_id already exists.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Here is a snippet of the changes that I tried doing:

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:user_id)
  end
  
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  
  def create
      @users = User.new(user_params)
      if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = "#{@user.user_id} was successfully created."
        redirect_to movies_path
      else
        flash[:notice] = "#{@user.user_id} is already taken."
      end
      render 'new'
  end
end

And now I get: undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass

Comment: You want to redirect them if the user_id already exists or if the email already exists?

Comment: If the user_id already exists. I think I was able to figure this out. 

if @user.save
        flash[:notice] = ""
        redirect_to path
      else
        flash[:notice] = ""
        render 'new'